How to setup Bearer Token in postnab Post request in post-script
I created a post request in post-script section all setup fine but issue i was facing in bearer token setup in header. I want to read bearer token value from environment var and token value also correct and I have checked via console log but how i can use token value in header.
If I pass whole token in header after bearer then it works but I want pass token value as var.
Here is the code-
const token=pm.environment.get('bearerToken');
url: url,
method: 'POST',
header: {
     'content-type': 'application/json',
     'Authorization': 'Bearer token',
     'X-PB-AUTH-ISSUER' : 'psapi'
    
}


you have to set you token in the postman authorization header and click </> icon on the right-side vertical bar then generate script for the request by choose your desire language.

sorry couldn't get you ,the current/main  request fetch auth token in header from environment  var  and working but I had call post request in script section so for that post request how i can provide bearer token in header parameters inside script.

in postman the secod option is "Authorization" click on that in this section there is optoin "Auth Type" select bearer token and paste your token  in text box  which is in the next section  after that you have an button on the right side </> click on that an post man provide you code for full request with payload and token

these option are showing below the url bar in postman

Finally after spending hours found solution-
  const token=pm.environment.get('bearerToken')
 
 header: 
        {
         'content-type': 'application/json',
         'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token    ,
         'X-PB-AUTH-ISSUER' : 'psapi'
        }

